# Global existence and uniqueness of solution for a first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Suppose we have a set of $n$ autonomous ODEs:

$\frac{dx_1}{dt} = f_1(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n),$
$\frac{dx_2}{dt} = f_2(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n),$
$\cdots,$
$\frac{dx_n}{dt} = f_n(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$

where $f_i$ are polynomials. Moreover suppose the above differential equations imply

$\frac{d \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{dt} = 0$,

which implies $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$ can never blow up.

Does it always have a unique global solution given some initial values for $x_i$?

More generally, if a function is locally lipschitz, and we can guarantee that $x_i$ never blows up, is it enough to argue global existence and uniqueness?

Comment: What theorems of this type do you know, and why do you think they do not apply to this case?

Comment: I am not very familiar with this area. Could you point me to some resources which can help get to the answer?

Comment: You need the Picard-Lindelöf theorem in one of its variants, the name Cauchy-Lipschitz is also sometimes used. For uniqueness results alone the Grönwall lemma can be used, it can give sharper quantitative bounds over longer domains than the Banach fixed-point theorem used in the proof of P-L.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I read about Picard-Lindelöf theorem, and understood that local existence and uniqueness can be showed. I have edited my question with one more condition, and want to understand whether one can also show global convergence assuming the $x_i$ remain bounded?

Comment: Let $ S $ denote the set of all $ t > 0 $ such that there exists a unique solution on $ [0, t) $.  Consider $ t^* = \sup S $ and suppose it is finite.  I claim your unique solution $ \mathbf{x}(t) $ has a limit as $ t \rightarrow t^* $.   Now there is a unique solution about $ t^* $.  If we are careful we can argue that the solution about $ t^* $ can be "glued onto" the solution on $ [0, t^*) $ to obtain a unique solution on $ [0, t^* + \varepsilon) $ violating the definition of $ t^* $.

Comment: @JakeMirra You argue about the existence of limit of $x(t)$ by using the fact that $x(t)$ never blows up?

Comment: The system $x_1'=-x_2$, $x_2'=x_1$ has bounded but not converging solutions. If you meant the global existence of the solution, look after the concept of a maximal solution and its properties. In short, the maximal solution leaves every compact subset of the domain of the equation, for instance all cylinders around the initial condition.